# How to split a string by spaces but keeping the space if it is surrounded by other spaces in python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm trying to get this result:

```
input: "this is a   example"
output: ["this", "is", "a", " ", "example"]
```

But using `.split(" ")` I am getting this:

```
output: ["this", "is", "a", "", "", "example"]
```

Comment: What should be the result if the input is `"a    b"` (4 spaces)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It should be ```"a", "  ", "b"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.findall` we can try alternatively matching words or spaces which are surrounded on both sides by space:

```py
inp = "this is a   example"
parts = re.findall(r'\w+|(?<=[ ])\s+(?=[ ])', inp)
print(parts)  # ['this', 'is', 'a', ' ', 'example']
```

Comment: What are the `[]` for?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It is just a character class containing the space character, for readability.

Comment: Okay. Because `(?<= )` seemed to work equally.

Comment: @mkrieger1 ... and that's harder to read and it could be mistaken that there is no space there at all.  Hence my comment above.